# How to do PDF Flattening using IText7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itext, itext7

I am previously flattening pdf form, annotation and freeText using ITextSharp in the code mentioned below:

```
 var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)
                {
                    FormFlattening = true,
                    AnnotationFlattening = true,
                    FreeTextFlattening = true
                };
```

I tried to do it in the below code but it is flattening only Form and not working for Text and Annotation:

```
   PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
    
    form.FlattenFields();
```

I want to know that how I can do the same thing using IText7 instead of ItextSharp?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Last time I checked there was no annotation flattening feature in iText 7. You can implement it yourself, though, by generalizing the form flattening code therein.